# application: not a procedure drracket scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, non-procedure-application

```
(define (layer li)
  (cond ((null? l) li)
        ((null? (cdr li)) (list (car li)))
        (else ((cons (list (car li)) (layer (cdr (li))))))))
```

This is my code above.

I'm trying to run (layer '(1 2 3))

but I keep getting this error message below.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

. . application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: '(1 2 3)
  arguments...: [none]

Comment: You have `((` before `cons`, why?

Comment: In most other languages, adding a few parentheses around an expression is either insignificant or a syntax error. Lisp-y languages are different.

Comment: `((something argument))` is the same as `something(argument)()` in C languages. Can you imagine what would happen if you add extra `()` in the end of function calls? Also you have undefined variable `l` and you are calling `li` as a function.